# How I can reverse multi words in a String by Stack keeping in order

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I have this string for example:

```
"rome lucy blue"
```

and I want to obtain this one:

```
"emor ycul eulb"
```

by using of a Stack.

I'm able to reverse only in this way:

```
"eulb ycul emor"
```

Follow the code:

```
public static String solution(String s) {

        Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char chr = s.charAt(i);
            stack.push(chr);
        }
        String output = "";
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            char chr = stack.pop();
            output = output + chr;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I tried to use another loop but I have the same result.

Comment: Well, you'll need to look for spaces.

Comment: @AndyTurner: ah, do you suggest to do pop when I meet a single space?

Comment: I suppose you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the idea you said in the comment. For each character in the string, if it's a space pop and append everything in the stack to the result, otherwise push it onto the stack.

```
public static String reverseWords(String str) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch)) {
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) res.append(stack.pop());
            res.append(ch);
        } else {
            stack.push(ch);
        }
    }

    // Handle anything left in the stack 
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        res.append(stack.pop());
    }

    return res.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep your code, you can do this way :

```
public static String solution(String s) {

        String[] tab = s.split(" "); 
        Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        String output = "";
        //Iterate over the words of the sentence
        for(String word : tab){

            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                char chr = word.charAt(i);
                stack.push(chr);
            }

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                char chr = stack.pop();
                output += chr;
            }
            output+=" ";
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I add a few lines, just split the sentence into an words array, and then you do **your** code on each word, don't forgot to put a escape after each and you're done

Answer (score 0):

Finally, follows my solution.

```
public static String solution(String s) {

        String[] input1array = s.split(" ");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i< input1array.length; i++ ){

            StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(input1array[i]);
            result.append(rev.reverse());

            if(i != input1array.length - 1 ){
                result.append(" ");
            }

        }
       return result.toString();
    }
```